# How do I check my accepted answers on others post?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to check only my accepted answers on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/). I know to check my [accepts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12418/bala?tab=activity&sort=accepts), but I don't know where to check my accepted answers on others post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
user:me isaccepted:yes
```

#### [Result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12418+isaccepted%3Ayes)

Comment: thanks, better add this line "In search-box use". It will help others too.

Comment: That info is available if you click on *advanced search* on the search result page on the right.